# How to handle low reputation users editing highly voted posts / high reputation users posts

Tags: support, suggested-edits, reputation

While reviewing the suggested edits queue, very often I find users with low reputation trying to edit questions / answers belonging to high reputation users.

This is an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32118531

I understand, of course, there's no limitation based on users reputation: one could genuinely propose edits to a post unregarding of their experience on SO. With that said, I sometimes find the same edit-proposing user kind of "tailoring" highly voted posts / posts belonging to high reputation members.

To be clear, it seems to me that certain users are trying to get their avatar shown at the post's bottom, as in "edited by ....".

I might be wrong, but I've seen this happening a lot of times.

How should I handle those kind of edits?

Comment: I doubt it. I think it's just that these posts have more visibility.

Comment: That particular edit was clearly incorrect as it changed the code and not just formatting.

Comment: I saw it has been rejected, I also noticed most of the times they get rejected for "no improvement". I guess that's the key interpretation.

Comment: *"it seems to me that certain users are trying to get their avatar shown at the post's bottom"* - no doubt, Stack Overflow is visited by millions of people so whatever argument you can come up with, even very unlikely ones, are probably going to be true when you ambiguously speak of "certain" people which can be one or thousands.

Comment: @Gimby I know, sentences like that can be applied to any context. I'm sorry I can't explain it better, just that "certain people" do anything possible, in order to put something inside their CV.

Comment: Re *"get their avatar shown at the post's bottom"*: I highly doubt that is the motive. It is more likely related to the *R* word.

Comment: @PeterMortensen sorry for asking this, but what's the "R word"?

Comment: @GrafiCode Reputation!  You get +2 when a suggested edit is approved.

Comment: GrafiCode in the gaming world those are called "gold farmers", but we no longer can use matching term here - so that's why I believe @PeterMortensen used ["R word"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269582) .

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard/read someone say that edits are helpful to someone's resume. Unless you're applying to a job that requires editing work or community engagement, I don't think that would be relevant. (And even then the point ought to be showing that you made *good* edits, not that you happened to be the last person to edit the post.)

Comment: @notarobot These weren't mistakes. I see nothing wrong with the current code.

Comment: @notarobot Can you explain why would that be a mistake?

Comment: @Dharman reviewer had proposed to change `<div>` with `</div>` (twice), I think that's what notarobot is asking about

Comment: Since I can see that a lot of confusion was created when the asker omitted the optional closing tags, I decided to add them to the MCVE. The suggested edit proposed to completely alter the HTML structure. If you are not sure if the code change is a formatting one of changes the meaning, the safe option is to reject the edit.

Answer (score 27):

Don't look at the user's reputation when reviewing suggested edits. It may bias your opinion and unfairly impact the decision. It doesn't matter how much reputation the original author has or the person who suggested the edit. If it improves the post, approve it, otherwise reject it.